# Diminishing return with time series data

Tags: statistics, time-series

Let say I have got two time series and I would like to know if there is some kind of diminishing return property between those two time series. Namely, there is a decrease  in the marginal output of the first one as you increase the second one. How would you proceed? I guess you should detrend the time series first, eventually removing the seasonality as well? Do you have example on internet/books of such study?